# How can I tab into a button inside Material UI Autocomplete custom popper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

I am working on a customization of Material UI's Autocomplete. I've customized the Popper component to include a button at the end of the options list, however I need to make this button accessible via the keyboard (via the Tab button, for example).

I have tried adding the `tabIndex=0` property to the button, but this doesn't change the default behavior - pressing Tab closed the Autocomplete.

What can I do to make the button reachable via keyboard commands?

Link to sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-butterfly-f4rn8z?file=/demo.tsx:0-1072

```
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@mui/material/Autocomplete";
import Popper from "@mui/material/Popper";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
];

export default function ComboBox() {
  const handleNotFound = () => {
    alert("Not found");
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
      PopperComponent={(props) => (
        <Popper {...props} placement="bottom">
          {props.children}
          <div>
            <Button type="button" tabIndex={0} onMouseDown={handleNotFound}>
              I don't see my movie
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Popper>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: You probably need to look at the event handlers. I'm guessing the blur() event (focus out) dismisses the dropdown list. You'd have to override that or set the blur() event to happen on the parent container.

Comment: Isn’t this control problematic on another level? According to ARIA, a `listbox` only can contain `option`s and `group`s of them. A button inside a listbox is not allowed, neither expected by users. There is no way to expose to AT that after the list there still is a button, which is shown inside the list, but doesn’t adhere to its keyboard controls. I believe it should simply be the list’s last option.

Comment: @Andy Good points, but in my implementation above, the button lies outside of the listbox; the Popper has two children elements at the same level, the listbox and the div containing the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid in terms of ARIA there are not many options.

#### Limitations set by ARIA

> Authors MUST ensure the popup element associated with a `combobox` has a role of `listbox`…

In other words, the element that is hidden and shown *is* the `listbox`, there is no way to add another container.

> List boxes contain children whose role is `option` or elements whose role is `group` which in turn contain children whose role is `option`.

This forbids any other role (except generic or none) inside the `listbox`, so no `button` can be placed inside the popup. i.e. listbox.

> Authors MUST manage focus on the following container roles:
> […]
> `listbox`

This practically forbids usage of <kbd>Tab</kbd> for navigation inside the popup, so `tabindex="0"` is not an option.

So you’d need the popup to have another role than `listbox` to break out of this logic. `dialog` would be an option, but this requires a lot of rendering and event logic to get right.

#### Options with Material UI and Popper

I recommend adding an “I don't see my movie” option inside the listbox, and maybe grouping the actual movies in a `group`. Or simply a button next to the combobox, to make things easier.

##### Grouped movies and Not found option

For better orientation, [grouping options](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#grouped) by found movies and other would help to distinguish “I don’t see my movie” from actual movies.

You then can use the `onChange` event to react to the user picking that option.

```js
const moviesGroup = "Matching Movies";

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { label: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994, isMovie: moviesGroup },
  { label: "The Godfather", year: 1972, isMovie: moviesGroup },
  { label: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974, isMovie: moviesGroup },
];

const options = [
  ...top100Films,
  { label: "I don’t find my movie", isMovie: "Other Options" }
];

export default function ComboBox() {
  const handleNotFound = () => {
    alert("Not found");
  }

  const onChange = (_, o) => {
    if (o.isMovie !== moviesGroup) {
      handleNotFound();
    }
  }

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={options}
      groupBy={(option) => option.isMovie}
      onChange={onChange}
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
    />
  );
}
```