# Including an extra button in an accessible autocomplete listbox

Tags: autocomplete, frontend, accessibility, web-frontend, wai-aria

I've implemented an autocomplete component in Angular using the aria-activedescendant attribute, so that the focus can remain in the  for the filtering functionality to work.

I have a design to follow that looks like something along the lines of the next picture. I need to include a "special option" / button at the bottom that opens a modal. This is a challenge for me because I don't know which role this element should have, as it is not an actual option to be selected.

[image]

I haven't found any information about this yet, and I guess the design is quite custom. I've evaluated the following options, but I would like to avoid them if a better solution already exists:

- Including it as another role="option" and a custom callback to be executed on "option selection".
- Adding a custom key with a description.

Comment: The only allowed roles within a `listbox` are `optiongroup` and `option`. I remember somebody else ask the same question, I’m trying to find it…

Comment: If the special option is not dependent on user input, it would not be an [ARIA `autocomplete`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-autocomplete). Is this the case for you?

Comment: I found the question. It was specific to Angular UI, but at its core it’s the very same situation (button inside a listbox). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76684915/how-can-i-tab-into-a-button-inside-material-ui-autocomplete-custom-popper/76754995#76754995 Let me know if it clarifies things for you.

Comment: @Andy the special option is just a button, it is not dependant on the user input. However the rest of the items of the list is dependant on the input, as they are filtered. Moreover, the list implements the listbox pattern. You said that is wouldnt be an ARIA autocomplete. Then what should it be from an ARIA point of view?

Comment: @Andy I've reviewed the other question, but I disagree on some things:
"Authors MUST ensure the popup element associated with a combobox has a role of listbox…" I dont believe that forbids having a parent element as long as the combobox and the listbox are linked.

Comment: Hm. You’re right it doesn’t. But then again, the input MUST be linked with the listbox via `aria-controls`, and one would expect focus to go into the listbox.

Comment: Yeah, i'm using aria-activedescendant, so it kind of makes it harder to implement an interactive element I guess...

Comment: This is what's come to be known as a "secondary action". The ARIA folks have flagged an implementation of secondary as a priority. See: https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1440